# Windows terminal changes title bar name when working with git bash after running npm scripts

Tags: windows, terminal, git-bash

When I use windows terminal with git-bash after running some npm scripts (run node server, or starting react application) the title bar name changes from directory name to windows cmd.exe(with full path), it doesn't happen if I use git-bash separately. Suppressing title change in wt settings doesn't help because if it's turned on the directory path doesn't appear. I want windows terminal to always show current working directory in the title bar. Is there any solutions for that?

[terminal showing directory path in title bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z85m4.jpg)

[terminal title arter npm run (running express.js)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVzkh.jpg)

Comment: Please post the code or error in question, not an image

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.